# Create and bind mount file in Docker

Tags: docker

The [Docker documentation about bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) states that:

> The file or directory does not need to exist on the Docker host already. It is created on demand if it does not yet exist.

This is true for folders: if I bind mount as:

> docker run -v $PWD/mydir:/mydir image:version

then the `mydir` folder is created and bind mounted in the container. But I cannot find the syntax for doing the same thing for a file either at the above linked page nor anywhere else.

Comment: I don't think you can. If the host file does not exist, Docker creates a directory and maps that.

Comment: But then why the official doc states what I reported in the first quote of my question? It clearly states "THE FILE or directory..."

Comment: I know. But I can't get it to do it. One thing to consider that might explain why it works the way it does is: How would Docker know that you intended to mount a file if it doesn't exist on the host?

Comment: A bit further down on the page it says "If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, -v creates the endpoint for you. *It is always created as a directory.*" (their emphasis). Seems like the docs are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is inconsistent. There's an open issue on it: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/10133

Docker always creates a directory if the host path doesn't exist. Or fails if you use the `--mount` syntax.

Comment: I susoected this, thanks for confirming!